# Osmbonuspack 5.5 and NominatimPOIProvider (poi along route)

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid with osmbonuspack 5.5. I’d l like to thank the developers for their great work :-).
( I’m not using the latest osmbonuspack, because this version (5.5) is the latest version supporting roadManager, or let’s say I wasn’t able to get roadManager to work with the latest version)

I’m using `ArrayList<POI> pois = poiProvider.getPOIAlong ( with NominatimPOIProvider)` to find pois along a route. This work great, but on longer routes (e.g. longer than 100 km) Nominatim only finds pois very close to my route disregarding the value `routewidth= ….`.

Is this a limitation from Nominatim? Can anyone give me a hint how to expand the poi search along a route? Maybe with a different provider?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Nominatim doesn't support a feature like "POIs along a route" as far as I know, so this must be somehow simulated by osmdroid/osmbonuspack by making multiple calls along the route. This won't help you solving your problem, though :)

Comment: Anyhow, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominatim really provides this feature - however, undocumented.

But it also has an hardcoded limit on number of POI results: 50 max. Even if you set the maxResults parameter to more.

Maybe your search on a long route is reaching this limit?

As far as I know, only Nominatim service is providing this "search along the route" feature.

Possibility: install Nominatim software on your own server, and increase this hardcoded limit...

Comment: Hi MKer! Thank you very much for bringing light into the darkness :-) !

Comment: Thanks Stan! You are even allowed to vote for relevant answers ! :-)